# Option menu только на определённых страницах

Tags: android

Как сделать что бы Option menu появлялось только на определённых страницах.
Что бы на этой странице Option menu был:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А на этой странице ActionBar был чист:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаю option menu таким образом:
xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
      android:id="@+id/Menu"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/Save"
            android:title="@string/Save"
    />
    <item
7           android:id="@+id/Refresh"
            android:title="@string/Refresh"
    />
</menu>`
```

Kotlin:

```
`

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    if (item != null) {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.Save->onSave()
            R.id.Refresh->onRefresh()
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я помню достаточно в onPrepareOptionsMenu проверять нужное условие и если меню не нужно - возвращать false.

Answer (score 2):

```
fun onClickAccept(view: View){//событие при котором открывается новое окно 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Accept=true//Метка что окно открылось
    invalidateOptionsMenu()
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}

override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    return if(Accept) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)//показываем option menu
    }else{
        false//скрываем option menu
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ты так же можешь в методе onCreateOptionsMenu получить итем ( предварительно объявив его в классе )

```
menuitem = menu.getItem(index) // индекс по порядку в xml разметке, начиная с 0
```

А затем в любом месте кода

```
menuitem.setVisible(false);
// если это в методе, который вызывается при старте, то добавь if (menuitem != null )
```

Если итемов с атрибутом `app:showAsAction="never"` нет или они невидимы, "трех точек сверху" не будет.